# Qt Signal Not Being Emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

I have a `QTcpSocket` inside of a class which is inside of my `QMainWindow`. I need to relay  the `connected()`, `disconnected()`, and `readyRead()` signals to the QMainWindow. Doing this should be quite simple just connecting the socket's signals to my custom class's slots. Then emitting signals from my custom class to my mainwindow's slots, right? I have done just that but to no avail. Even when running `emit client->sendData("data")` from the mainwindow slot. I get a successful SIGNAL/SLOT connection. However when emitting these from my custom class I get no data pass whatsoever. Here is my relevant code:

Mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    client = new Client(this);
    qDebug() << "1st success = " << connect(client, &Client::sendData, this, &MainWindow::dataReady);
    qDebug() << "2nd success = " << connect(client, &Client::clientConnected, this, &MainWindow::clientConnected);
    qDebug() << "3rd success = " << connect(client, &Client::clientDisconnected, this, &MainWindow::clientDisconnected);
    emit client->sendData("Hello!");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonConnect_clicked()
{
    if (isConnected)
        client->disconnect();
    if (client)
        client->connectToServer(ui->lineEditServerIp->text(), ui->lineEditServerPort->text().toInt());
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonDisconnect_clicked()
{
    client->disconnectToServer();
}

void MainWindow::dataReady(QByteArray data)
{
    qDebug() << data;
}

void MainWindow::clientConnected()
{
    isConnected = true;
    ui->lineEditServerIp->setEnabled(false);
    ui->lineEditServerPort->setEnabled(false);
    ui->pushButtonConnect->setEnabled(false);
    ui->pushButtonDisconnect->setEnabled(true);
}

void MainWindow::clientDisconnected()
{
    isConnected = false;
    ui->lineEditServerIp->setEnabled(true);
    ui->lineEditServerPort->setEnabled(true);
    ui->pushButtonConnect->setEnabled(true);
    ui->pushButtonDisconnect->setEnabled(false);
}
```

MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "client.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void dataReady(QByteArray data);

    void clientConnected();

    void clientDisconnected();

private slots:

    void on_pushButtonConnect_clicked();

    void on_pushButtonDisconnect_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Client *client;

    bool isConnected;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Client.cpp:

```
#include "client.h"

Client::Client(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(bytesWritten(qint64)));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}

bool Client::connectToServer(QString ipAddress, int port)
{
    if (socket && socket->state() != QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        qDebug() << "Now connecting to:" << ipAddress << ":" << port;

        socket->connectToHost(ipAddress, port);

        if (!socket->waitForConnected(3000))
        {
            qDebug() << "Connection error: " << socket->errorString();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Successfully connected!";
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (!socket)
    {
        qDebug() << "Socket unitialized.";
        return false;
    }

    else if (socket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        qDebug() << "Socket already connect to" << socket->peerName() << ".";
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}

void Client::disconnectToServer()
{
    socket->disconnectFromHost();
}

void Client::connected()
{
    qDebug() << "Successfully connected.";
    emit this->clientConnected();

}

void Client::disconected()
{
    qDebug() << "Disconnected from server.";
    emit this->clientDisconnected();
}

void Client::bytesWritten(qint64 bytes)
{
    qDebug() << bytes;
}

void Client::readyRead()
{
    QByteArray data = socket->readAll();
    qDebug() << "Server: " << data;
    emit this->sendData(data);
}
```

Client.h:

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDebug>

class Client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Client(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    bool connectToServer(QString ipAddress, int port);
    void disconnectToServer();

signals:
    void sendData(QByteArray data);

    void clientConnected();

    void clientDisconnected();

public slots:
    void connected();

    void disconected();

    void bytesWritten(qint64 bytes);

    void readyRead();

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;

};

#endif // CLIENT_H
```

Moc_client.cpp:

```
/****************************************************************************
** Meta object code from reading C++ file 'client.h'
**
** Created by: The Qt Meta Object Compiler version 67 (Qt 5.9.0)
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
*****************************************************************************/

#include "../../FLClient/client.h"
#include <QtCore/qbytearray.h>
#include <QtCore/qmetatype.h>
#if !defined(Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION)
#error "The header file 'client.h' doesn't include <QObject>."
#elif Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION != 67
#error "This file was generated using the moc from 5.9.0. It"
#error "cannot be used with the include files from this version of Qt."
#error "(The moc has changed too much.)"
#endif

QT_BEGIN_MOC_NAMESPACE
QT_WARNING_PUSH
QT_WARNING_DISABLE_DEPRECATED
struct qt_meta_stringdata_Client_t {
    QByteArrayData data[9];
    char stringdata0[86];
};
#define QT_MOC_LITERAL(idx, ofs, len) \
    Q_STATIC_BYTE_ARRAY_DATA_HEADER_INITIALIZER_WITH_OFFSET(len, \
    qptrdiff(offsetof(qt_meta_stringdata_Client_t, stringdata0) + ofs \
        - idx * sizeof(QByteArrayData)) \
    )
static const qt_meta_stringdata_Client_t qt_meta_stringdata_Client = {
    {
QT_MOC_LITERAL(0, 0, 6), // "Client"
QT_MOC_LITERAL(1, 7, 8), // "sendData"
QT_MOC_LITERAL(2, 16, 0), // ""
QT_MOC_LITERAL(3, 17, 4), // "data"
QT_MOC_LITERAL(4, 22, 15), // "clientConnected"
QT_MOC_LITERAL(5, 38, 18), // "clientDisconnected"
QT_MOC_LITERAL(6, 57, 12), // "bytesWritten"
QT_MOC_LITERAL(7, 70, 5), // "bytes"
QT_MOC_LITERAL(8, 76, 9) // "readyRead"

    },
    "Client\0sendData\0\0data\0clientConnected\0"
    "clientDisconnected\0bytesWritten\0bytes\0"
    "readyRead"
};
#undef QT_MOC_LITERAL

static const uint qt_meta_data_Client[] = {

 // content:
       7,       // revision
       0,       // classname
       0,    0, // classinfo
       5,   14, // methods
       0,    0, // properties
       0,    0, // enums/sets
       0,    0, // constructors
       0,       // flags
       3,       // signalCount

 // signals: name, argc, parameters, tag, flags
       1,    1,   39,    2, 0x06 /* Public */,
       4,    0,   42,    2, 0x06 /* Public */,
       5,    0,   43,    2, 0x06 /* Public */,

 // slots: name, argc, parameters, tag, flags
       6,    1,   44,    2, 0x0a /* Public */,
       8,    0,   47,    2, 0x0a /* Public */,

 // signals: parameters
    QMetaType::Void, QMetaType::QByteArray,    3,
    QMetaType::Void,
    QMetaType::Void,

 // slots: parameters
    QMetaType::Void, QMetaType::LongLong,    7,
    QMetaType::Void,

       0        // eod
};

void Client::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        Client *_t = static_cast<Client *>(_o);
        Q_UNUSED(_t)
        switch (_id) {
        case 0: _t->sendData((*reinterpret_cast< QByteArray(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 1: _t->clientConnected(); break;
        case 2: _t->clientDisconnected(); break;
        case 3: _t->bytesWritten((*reinterpret_cast< qint64(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
        case 4: _t->readyRead(); break;
        default: ;
        }
    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::IndexOfMethod) {
        int *result = reinterpret_cast<int *>(_a[0]);
        void **func = reinterpret_cast<void **>(_a[1]);
        {
            typedef void (Client::*_t)(QByteArray );
            if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&Client::sendData)) {
                *result = 0;
                return;
            }
        }
        {
            typedef void (Client::*_t)();
            if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&Client::clientConnected)) {
                *result = 1;
                return;
            }
        }
        {
            typedef void (Client::*_t)();
            if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) == static_cast<_t>(&Client::clientDisconnected)) {
                *result = 2;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

const QMetaObject Client::staticMetaObject = {
    { &QObject::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_Client.data,
      qt_meta_data_Client,  qt_static_metacall, nullptr, nullptr}
};


const QMetaObject *Client::metaObject() const
{
    return QObject::d_ptr->metaObject ? QObject::d_ptr->dynamicMetaObject() : &staticMetaObject;
}

void *Client::qt_metacast(const char *_clname)
{
    if (!_clname) return nullptr;
    if (!strcmp(_clname, qt_meta_stringdata_Client.stringdata0))
        return static_cast<void*>(const_cast< Client*>(this));
    return QObject::qt_metacast(_clname);
}

int Client::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    _id = QObject::qt_metacall(_c, _id, _a);
    if (_id < 0)
        return _id;
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        if (_id < 5)
            qt_static_metacall(this, _c, _id, _a);
        _id -= 5;
    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::RegisterMethodArgumentMetaType) {
        if (_id < 5)
            *reinterpret_cast<int*>(_a[0]) = -1;
        _id -= 5;
    }
    return _id;
}

// SIGNAL 0
void Client::sendData(QByteArray _t1)
{
    void *_a[] = { nullptr, const_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&_t1)) };
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 0, _a);
}

// SIGNAL 1
void Client::clientConnected()
{
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 1, nullptr);
}

// SIGNAL 2
void Client::clientDisconnected()
{
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 2, nullptr);
}
QT_WARNING_POP
QT_END_MOC_NAMESPACE
```

Comment: Maybe a bit off-topic, but you can actually connect a signal to a signal. You don't have to create a intermediate slot that only does an `emit` something. And the `this` keyword is indeed completely optional.

Comment: @AdrienLeravat how can I do this without making my QTcpSocket public?

Comment: For the `connected` signal for instance, you can keep the signals you have in your Client class, but instead of connecting signal to slot, you can connect the socket `connected` signal to your `Client::connected` signal, with the same syntax as usual

Comment: @AdrienLeravat I;ve done that, but still no difference. Not emitting.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think that would solve it, that was just a remark to make your code a bit simpler. My guess would be something related to qmake / Q_OBJECT macro. Have you tried running qmake manually from the "build" menu ?

Comment: @AdrienLeravat Thank you for the code simpler as it does help a bit. However, I have ran QMake and clean many times from the build menu and nope! Nothing helped.

Comment: I cannot spot anything obvious, a few things: Are you sure your MainWindow is not destroyed immediately ? What's the code that qmake implemented in your moc_client.h ? If you have a debug build of Qt, you can also try placing a break point at the emit to dig into Qt's code. You could also try the old connect syntax (with SIGNAL and SLOT macros), already bumped into a related issue with older Qt versions.

Comment: Are the slots of your Client catching the socket's signals properly? Is it only the communication between the window and the client that doesn't work, or also within the client itself?

Comment: @AdrienLeravat I use the MainWindow with a GUI so I think it stays active for the entirety of the application. I've added the moc_client.h code. Old syntax does nothin as it was the first thing I had tried.

Comment: @KjMag The slots catch the socket's signals correctly as I have used qDebugs on them to verify data and calls. I believe it is only in the client as if I call `emit client->sendData("123");` it will successfully emit the signal + emit the secondary signal in my MainWindow.

Comment: Sorry, but from that description I'm not sure: socket-Client is OK and Client-MainWindow is not OK? Is that right? Which Qt version do you use by the way?

Comment: @KjMag I am on Qt 5.9. My client has slots that were connected from the socket. They were called successfully as expected. I inserted emit statements into these slots that are supposed to emit to the MainWindow, but they are never called.

Comment: @KjMag Client -> MainWindow = FAIL    MainWindow -> Client = PASS   Socket -> Client = PASS

Comment: What if you replace emit this->sendData(data); by emit sendData(data); (remove this), try to rename signals  / slot in case you are overriding parent class methods